# Laravel 5.3 get boolean value from associative array

Tags: php, object, indexing, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a `ImageController` like this:

```
$image = Image::where('id', $id)->first();

return [
    'image' => $image,
    'image_360' => $image['360']
];
```

The previous lines return to the browser the following:

```
{
    "image": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "default.jpg",
        "360": 1,
    },
    "image_360": null
}
```

The `Image` migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->boolean('360');
```

The `Image` model:

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', '360'];

    protected $casts = [
        '360' => 'boolean'
    ];
}
```

Why `$images['360']` returns `null` if its value is `true`?

Comment: you need to cast it to `boolean`.

Comment: If I cast it like `(bool)$image['360']`, it returns `false` when the expected value is `true`

Comment: var_dump($image['360']) and var_dump($image) ???

Comment: `NULL` and `object(App\Image)`

Comment: I think here you use a number as the column of a table, it may have some issues here.

Comment: var_dump($image[\`360\`])  ?? note here is not the ' . Here is parsed as code the 360 are in two `

Comment: `var_dump($image[360])` returns `NULL` too. In the database the column `360` is `tinyint(1)` type

Comment: it's not 360, i mean 360 with  two `

Comment: `var_dump($image['360'])`, `var_dump($image[360])` and `var_dump($image[\`360\`])` return `NULL`

Comment: I cannot figure it out now.  but array_values($image)[2] may be a walkaround. Though it's not a good one.

Comment: `array_values($image)` returns an error because `$image` is an `object(App\Image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround way: I've tryed many ways but havenot get a direct way to access the number value as descripted in this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41711470/6521116)

```
return [
    'image' => $image,
    'image_360' => array_values($image->toArray())[2];
];
```